# Testing to see if $\ell$ is of split or nonsplit multiplicative reduction

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Suppose an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ has multiplicative reduction at $\ell$. Are there any other ways of seeing if $\ell$ is of split or nonsplit reduction aside from computing $\widetilde{E}_{\textrm{ns}}(\mathbb{F}_{\ell})$ or computing tangent lines at the node?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could check whether $-c_6$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_\ell$. If it is, the reduction is split.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#Algebraic_definition) for a definition of $c_6$. This is just a nice shortcut for calculating the slope of the tangent lines, so there is no new theory here.